# Is the Two-Proportions Z-Test the correct test to use when trying to compare specific proportions?

Tags: r, fishers-exact-test

Hi supposed I have a table like this.

```
    Response total_cells group total percent
1  resistant         254   Pre 13949   1.821
2 responsive         145   Pre 12451   1.165
3  resistant         443  Post 10823   4.093
4 responsive         460  Post 24153   1.905
```

I would like to know if there is statistical difference in portion between resistance in pre vs post.

I run the my test as such,

```
prop.test(x = c( count_tbl[3,]$total_cells , count_tbl[3,]$total)
          , n = c( count_tbl[4,]$total_cells , count_tbl[4,]$total))
```

is this the correct way to go about it?

here is the table

```
count_tbl = structure(list(Response = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("resistant", 
"responsive"), class = "factor"), total_cells = c(254L, 145L, 
443L, 460L), group = c("Pre", "Pre", "Post", "Post"), total = c(13949L, 
12451L, 10823L, 24153L), percent = c(1.821, 1.165, 4.093, 1.905
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: First thing to note is that `prop.test` actually does a chi-squared test rather than a z-test (though it's equivalent to the one-sample z-test for a two-sided alternative - whether both tests do or both tests don't do the corresponding continuity corrections). There's not a lone "the" correct test here, though your chosen one should be perfectly fine.  There's other tests that could be done; the help for `prop.test` even mentions one of them specifically. Your code setting up `x` and `n` for `prop.test` is wrong.

Comment: @Glen_b , yes my mistake I corrected the code.

Comment: I don't think that's the correct way to do the test, no. What hypothesis are you testing?

Comment: @Glen_b my hypothesis is that there should less percent of cells in the responsive group after treatment ( "Post" ) compare to the resistant group. What makes this complicated is that I need to take into consideration the total amount of cells since both groups have different numbers.